# Converting an array into an object with REQL

Tags: javascript, rethinkdb, reql

I'm looking for the most concise way to convert an array to an object while plucking the field used as the key for each result.

This is the solution I found, and I'm wondering if there's an easier way.

```
r.table('product').fold({}, function(products, product) {
  return products.merge(
    r.object(
      product('id').coerceTo('string'),
      product.without('id')
    )
  );
})
```

Thanks!

---

#### Example

```
// Input:
[{ id: 0, price: 19.99 }, { id: 1, price: 24.99 }]

// Output:
{ "0": { price: 19.99 }, "1": { price: 24.99 } }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert, but AFAIK, using `fold()` directly on a table will "stop subsequent commands from being parallelized":
https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/optimization/

So, if I'm not mistaken, if the order is not important it might be better to choose `reduce()` over `fold()`, e.g.

```or-tag-here
table.map(function(row) {
    return r.object(
      row('id').coerceTo('string'), row.without('id')
    )
  })
  .reduce(function(left, right) {
    return left.merge(right)
  })
```